# What is the dimension of the kernel of a linear transformation from infinite dimensional to finite dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let **T:V→W** be a linear transformation where **V** is an **infinite**-dimensional vector space and **W** is a **finite**-dimensional vector space. What is the dimension of the kernel?

---

Hello everyone. Sorry my English, it's not my first language.

I tried doing this:

T(v1)=w1

T(v2)=w2

...

T(vn)=wn

But V has infinite vectors, so remaining vectors are in the kernel.

I don't know if I can use dim V = dim KerT + dim ImT here.

I'm not sure of the things I said. If someone may help me I would appreciate a lot. Thank you very much for attention!

[image: what i'm trying to say]

Comment: What is the point of writing down $T(v_k) = w_k$ where the $v_k,w_k$ are undefined???

Comment: Sorry about this, i tried to say that v belongs to V and w belong to W.

Comment: That is still meaningless.

Comment: v ∈ V and w ∈ W

Comment: I understand that. But what is the relevance to the question other than noise? Without specifying $v_k,w_k$ it means nothing.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cecnw.png

Comment: Look, I have a passing familiarity with algebra, that is not the issue. The issue is that unless you specify what $v_k, w_k$ are the statement $T(v_k) = w_k$ is nothing but a bunch of symbols. Nowhere in your question do you specify what the $v_k,w_k$ are.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the dimension of the kernel is finite, so $\ker f$ has $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ as basis.

If $\{f(x_1),\dots,f(x_m)\}$ is a basis of the image of $f$, prove that
$$
\{x_1,\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_n\}
$$
is a spanning set for $V$ (actually a basis).

Comment: May I use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3070298/how-can-i-prove-this-property-in-a-linear-transformation?noredirect=1#comment6330417_3070298?

Comment: If we have a linear transformation T:V→W and the dimension of V is greater than the dimension of W, then the kernel of T has to have a dimension at least as large as the difference. So, when V is infinite dimensional and W has a finite dimension, then the kernel has to be infinite dimensional.

Comment: My question is, can I use the rank-nullity theorem in this case? When I have an infinite dimensional vector space?

Comment: @Harry I didn't use the rank-nullity theorem. What I proved (in a way very similar to the theorem) that if the image is finite dimensional *and* the kernel is finite dimensional, then the domain is finite dimensional as well. Hence in your case the dimension of the kernel must be infinite.

Comment: I understood! Thank you very much for your help. I'm very happy now.