# How can I prove this property in a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

If you have a linear transformation **T:V→W** and the dimension of **V** is greater than the dimension of **W**, then the kernel of **T** has to have a dimension **at least as large as the difference**.

For example, a transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^7\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ has to have a kernel of dimension 4 or greater.

---

May I use this?

$\dim⁡ \ker(T)+ \dim⁡ R(T) = \dim ⁡V$

$\dim \ker (T) = \dim V - \dim R(T)$

But $R(T)$ belongs to $W$, so the dimension of $R(T)$ has to be equal or less than dimension of $W$ (How can I prove this?). So,

$\dim \ker (T) \geq \dim V - \dim W$

And $\dim V > \dim W$, so $\dim V - \dim W$ is positive.

Is this right?

---

May I use this property to say when V is infinite dimensional and W has a finite dimension, then the kernel has to be infinite dimensional?

---

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This is correct indeed. The third line uses the fact that vector spaces can't have two bases of different size. If $\dim W = m$ then there are up to $m$ independent vectors in $W$ and therefore also in $Im(T)$.

Comment: See this question it probably answers your last question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752056/does-the-rank-nullity-theorem-hold-for-infinite-dimensional-v

Comment: Thank you, Yanko! :)

Comment: You are saving my life!